# I think it is the best product on the market, isn't it? or don't you?

Tags: grammar, question-tags

I think it is the best product on the market,_______?
isn't it or don't you?
Can I use isn't?

Comment: The answer would be clear if you write out the whole questions once with full repetition. "Isn't it (the best product on the market)?" and "Don't you (think it is the best product on the marker)?" The abbreviated questions omit the part in parentheses because you just said those words a moment ago.

Comment: To analyze it I would think it of the two parts as two complete sentences:  "I think it is the best product on the market. Don't you (think so, too)?" In writing, the way you wrote it, by attaching the tag question with a comma, is fine, too. If the question becomes too long, then I feel that the comma should be replaced with a period or a semicolon. But that's more of a writing style issue.

Comment: Note that in some varieties of English _isn't it_ is more or less invariable as a tag question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, though they mean different things:

> I think it is the best product on the market, isn't it?

Here you are stating your thoughts, and asking if it is the best product.

> I think it is the best product on the market, don't you?

Here you are stating your thoughts, and then asking if they also think the same thing.

The first is asking if it is the best product (the fact that you think so is ancillary to the question). The second you are asking about their thoughts -- what they think, whether they share the same thoughts as you.

In most circumstances, in casual conversation, it would have the same basic meaning, however, the emphasis is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar meaning in both cases. Depending on the context, I feel there could be subtle differences.

> I think it is the best product on the market, isn't it?

The speaker **doesn't know for sure** if it is indeed the *best* product and asks for the listener to confirm that — but the listener might not know or care.

- *L:* I think it is. / Not sure / Well, it doesn't matter, as long as it does the job.

> I think it is the best product on the market, don't you?

The speaker believes **it is** the *best* product and expects, when asking '*...don't you?*', the listener (L) to agree with them — or state a reason for disagreeing:

- *L:* I do, yeah — there's nothing really like it.

**OR:**

- *L:* Not really; [that product] is much better to be honest with you.